How to set aplication icon in PyQt6?
I have a small application on Python with PyQt6.
Trying to set an icon with
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ui\app.ico'))

without any success. It sets window icon but the taskbar icon remains unchanged.
I also tried adding
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)

from this answer, but this did not help as well.
Also I tried png icon with no success.
Icon size is 128x128. I am using Windows 11 23H2, Python 3.10.11, PyQt 6.7.0.
Running application in Poetry 1.8.3 venv if this does matter.

First of all, never use backslashes in plain strings, since they are used as escape characters; always use: 1. standard forward slashes (/); 2. escaped backslashes (\\); 3. raw strings (r'some\path'). Then, have you tried to actually call window.setWindowIcon() (with window being the reference to the actual top level widget?

Thanks for your comment about backslashes. I always do this in correct way - just made a mistake in example code. Yes, I've tried to call setWindowIcon() like you say. Unfortunately, no result.
